# how can i use scrollToOffset in useEffect React native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

what i'm trying to do is that when first rendering,
i want to scroll down as much as value of offset (which is 493) as by using useEffect and scrollToOffset

but if i use my code it doesn't work first rendering but when from second rendering it works... how can i run when first rendering?

what code should i fix?

this is my code

```
    const TodoList = ({replycomment}) => {

      const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
      const flatListRef = useRef()
      
    useEffect(() => {
      const node = flatListRef.current;
        node.scrollToOffset({ offset: 493, animated: true });
    },[]);

      return (
        
        <FlatList
        ref={flatListRef}
          style={{height}}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TodoItem
            onPress={() => {
              const node = flatListRef.current;
              if (node) {
                node.scrollToOffset({ offset: height, animated: true });
              }
            }}
            />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try delay in time like

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeOut(() => {
      const node = flatListRef.current;
      node.scrollToOffset({ offset: 493, animated: true });
  },400);
},[]);
```